# Document count query ignores PartitionKey

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am looking to get the count of all documents in a chosen partition. The following code however will return the count of all documents in the collection and costs 0 RU.

```
    var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);

    string command = "SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM Collection c";

    FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions()
    {
        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(BuildPartitionKey(contextName, domainName)),
        EnableCrossPartitionQuery = false
    };

    var count = client.CreateDocumentQuery<int>(collectionLink, command, feedOptions)
        .ToList()
        .First();
```

adding a `WHERE c.partition = 'blah'` clause to the query will work, but costs 3.71 RUs with 11 documents in the collection.

Why would the above code snippet return the Count of the whole Collection and is there a better solution to for getting the count of all documents in a chosen partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the query includes a filter against the partition key, like SELECT
>   * FROM c WHERE c.city = "Seattle", it is routed to a single partition. If the query does not have a filter on partition key, then it is
>   executed in all partitions, and results are merged client side.

You could check the logical steps the SDK performs from this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics#about-sql-query-execution) when we issue a query to Azure Cosmos DB.

> If the query is an aggregation like COUNT, the counts from individual
>   partitions are summed to produce the overall count.

So when you just use `SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM Collection c`, it is executed in all partitions and results are merged client side.

If you want to get the count of all documents in a chosen partition, you just add the `where c.partition = 'XX'` filter.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: So the `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` and `PartitionKey` properties in the feed options are ignored for all aggregation queries?

Comment: @Du-z I think it's about if you have query filter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is the worst database engine ever. Things like this make it totally worthless. I just spent an hour trying to figure out why my paging isn't working, only to discover that the partition key is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is actually a bug since I am having the same problem with the partition key set in both the query and the `FeedOptions`.

A similar issue has been reported here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/543

And Microsoft's response makes it sound like it is an SDK issue that is x64-specific.